# How to avoid stopping the recursive `check` target?

Tags: makefile, gnu-make, autotools, automake

My project has the following directory structure (some files hidden for
clarity):

```
Makefile.am
tests/
  Makefile.am
  a/
    Makefile.am
  b/
    Makefile.am
  c/
    Makefile.am
```

If I put all the tests to run that are in the `a/`, `b/`, and `c/`
subdirectories in the `TESTS` variable of `tests/Makefile.am`, then with
`make check` in `tests/`, all the tests run, even if one test in one of
the subdirectories fail. Assume this is the behaviour I want.

With this configuration, however, I cannot go to `b/`, for example, and
run `make check`: since there's no `TESTS` variable there, `make check`
does nothing.

So I put a `TESTS` variable in `a/Makefile.am`, `b/Makefile.am`, and
`c/Makefile.am`, and remove the `TESTS` variable from `tests/Makefile.am`. Now
I can go to `a/`, `b/`, or `c/` and run `make check` to test only specific
parts of the project. However, since each individual `make check` can
fail, now the "global" `make check` in `tests/` fails as soon as one
subdirectory fails, which is the expected behaviour of Make.

My current workaround is to use `make --keep-going check` in `tests/`, so
that, as per [make(1)](https://linux.die.net/man/1/make):

> Continue as much as possible after an error.  While the target that
>   failed, and those that depend on it, can‐ not be remade, the other
>   dependencies of these targets can be processed all the same.

This seems to run all the individual `make check` and exit with
something else than 0 if one of them fails.

I can also wrap this `make --keep-going check` in a new target, for
example:

```
test:
        $(MAKE) $(AM_MAKEFLAGS) --keep-going check
```

Now `make test` does what I want in `tests/`.

Is there anything more "Automaky" I could do to achieve the same goal?
Or is using `make --keep-going check` the expected method here if I
don't want Make to stop as soon as one subdirectory test fails?